# How do I clear the collection or the comments and names on the screen from the console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using the following code to insert data into mongo and am wondering how to I wipe it all from the console so my page isn't all cluttered. I guess I would also like to know how to selectively delete as well so i could select comment name entries and delete them.

live at http://tuts.meteor.com

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection('messages');


if (Meteor.is_client){

   ////////// Helpers for in-place editing //////////

  // Returns an event_map key for attaching "ok/cancel" events to
  // a text input (given by selector)
  var okcancel_events = function (selector) {
    return 'keyup '+selector+', keydown '+selector+', focusout '+selector;
  };

  // Creates an event handler for interpreting "escape", "return", and "blur"
  // on a text field and calling "ok" or "cancel" callbacks.
  var make_okcancel_handler = function (options) {
    var ok = options.ok || function () {};
    var cancel = options.cancel || function () {};

    return function (evt) {
      if (evt.type === "keydown" && evt.which === 27) {
        // escape = cancel
        cancel.call(this, evt);
      } else if (evt.type === "keyup" && evt.which === 13) {
        // blur/return/enter = ok/submit if non-empty
        var value = String(evt.target.value || "");
        if (value)
          ok.call(this, value, evt);
        else
          cancel.call(this, evt);
      }
    };
  };//added as test

    Template.entry.events = {};


  /*  Template.entry.events[okcancel_events('#messageBox')] = make_okcancel_handler({
      ok:function(text, event){
        var nameEntry = document.getElementById('name');
        if(nameEntry.value != ""){
          var ts = Date.now() / 1000;
          Messages.insert({name: nameEntry.value, message: text, time: ts});
          event.target.value = "";
        }//if statment ends
      }
    });
  */





    Template.entry.events['click #submit'] = function() {
        var nameEntry = document.getElementById('name');
        if(nameEntry.value != ""){
            var ts = Date.now() / 1000;
            Messages.insert({name: nameEntry.value, message: $('#messageBox').val(), time: ts});
        }
    }



  Template.messages.messages = function () {
    return Messages.find({}, { sort: {time: -1} });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[To erase it all:](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorreset)

```
meteor reset
```

To delete each one by query with the os console

```
meteor mongo
db.collectionname.remove({query})
```

Or you could just do it from your chrome/safari/firebug console if your collection is exposed to the client, which you could build a UI and use:

```
collectionname.remove({query})
```

*Tip*:

You can use [regexp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) to speed up and remove sets of documents matching a regular expression. e.g if I want to remove all values containing 'the' for the field `name`. This will work in the mongo console, server and client.

```
collectionname.remove({ name : { $regex: 'the', $options: 'i' }});
```

The `i` option makes the query case insensitive.

Of course `collecionname` is just a placeholder for whichever collection you decide to hit down.